# Render an eqexpl like an array

Tags: arrays

Could you improve my code, please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{eqexpl}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand{\Angolare}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}

\newcommand{\String}[1]{\mbox{string}\Tonde{#1}}

\begin{document}
\eqexplSetItemAlign{l}
\eqexplSetDelim{=}
\eqexplSetSpace{2cm}
\eqexplSetIntro{di cui}
\begin{eqexpl}
\item{$\String{i_j}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sezione }i_j}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_k}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sezione }i_{j_k}}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_{_h}}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sotto--sezione }i_{j_{k_h}}}$.
\end{eqexpl}
$\begin{array}{clcl}
\text{di cui}&\String{i_j}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sezione }i_j}\\
&\String{i_{j_k}}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sezione }i_{j_k}}\\
&\String{i_{j_{k_h}}}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sotto--sezione }i_{j_{k_h}}}
\end{array}$
\ebd{document}
```

That makes

[image: EqExPl=Array]

My objective is how edit the `\begin{eqexpl}...\end{eqexpl}` to render it equal to the `array` below.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have the `eqexpl` package but I strongly suspect `\eqexplSetSpace{2cm}` might have to do with it.

Comment: On CTAN there is the Documentation (6 pages) but I have difficulty to render this `eqexpl` an `array`. [HERE](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqexpl)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say this is the elegant approach or even that it "improves" the OP's code, but I make several changes:

1. I change the `Delim` to from `{=}` to `{\kern.65cm=\kern-.6cm}`
2. I change the `Space` from `{2cm}` to `{1cm}`
3. I change the `Intro` from `{di cui}` to `{~~di cui\hspace{-.75cm}}`

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{eqexpl}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\newcommand{\Angolare}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}

\newcommand{\String}[1]{\mbox{string}\Tonde{#1}}

\begin{document}
\eqexplSetItemAlign{l}
\eqexplSetDelim{\kern.65cm=\kern-.6cm}
\eqexplSetSpace{1cm}
\eqexplSetIntro{~~di cui\hspace{-.75cm}}
\begin{eqexpl}
\item{$\String{i_j}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sezione }i_j}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_k}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sezione }i_{j_k}}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_{_h}}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sotto--sezione }i_{j_{k_h}}}$.
\end{eqexpl}
$\begin{array}{clcl}
\text{di cui}&\String{i_j}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sezione }i_j}\\
&\String{i_{j_k}}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sezione }i_{j_k}}\\
&\String{i_{j_{k_h}}}&=&\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sotto--sezione }i_{j_{k_h}}}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but on my Overleaf this code create a bad compilation

Answer (score 1):

`\eqexplSetSpace{2cm}` will also increase the space between the introduction word and the rest so I would let `\eqexplSetSpace` to its default value (2mm). Anyway, the `eqexpl` environment can take an optional argument to custom the item width (bottom of p.4 in [the `eqexpl` documentation](https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/eqexpl/eqexpl.pdf)).

So, it can (nicely but differently from what you asked) look like this:
[image: LaTeX ouput]
With the corresponding MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{eqexpl}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Angolare}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\String}[1]{\mbox{string}\Tonde{#1}}

\begin{document}
\eqexplSetItemAlign{l}
\eqexplSetDelim{=}
\eqexplSetIntro{di cui}
\begin{eqexpl}[1.6cm]
\item{$\String{i_j}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sezione }i_j}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_k}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sezione }i_{j_k}}$;
\item{$\String{i_{j_{_h}}}$} $\Angolare{\text{lunghezza della sotto--sotto--sezione }i_{j_{k_h}}}$.
\end{eqexpl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but on my Overleaf this code create a bad compilation

Comment: @Puck What compiler do you use on Overleaf?

Comment: I use pdfLaTeX but also LaTeX